# Global auth_request for nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a server where I run multiple subdomains sites with nginx

each subdomain have a `server { ... }` block in configuration (in `sites-enabled` )

I want to add a **global** dynamic authentication backend (another http site) that will check requested subdomain and give access or ask user credentials

so the flow should be like

```
request stie1.example.com ---> [auth check in database] 
                                /              \
                              no               yes
                              /                  \
            show username/pass form        pass to site1.example.com
```

I found [auth_request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) module - but examples only about `server` context

and I want it on top level context (`http` context) - where of course  `location` directive is not available

So basically what I want is sort of global nginx middleware where I can run some code (i.e. python) to check if user have permission to view one of the hosted domains

any suggestions ?

Comment: You could create a common authentication config that proxy passes to the same endpoint and include it in each `server` block like `include auth_proxy.conf;`

Comment: Interesting question, seems no solution here as little can be done at http level. If you can manage the server level a simple inclusion @aergistal suggested seems the most viable approach

Answer (score 0):

It would perhaps help if you provide actual context for what it is exactly that you want done.

As per http://nginx.org/r/auth_request, the `auth_request` directive is actually allowed "two" levels up of the `location` context — both in the `server` as well as `http` contexts, so, there is absolutely nothing that should prevent you from enabling it globally for every single `server` in your nginx instance.

Otherwise, if you want it enabled only within certain `location` directives and/or only certain `server` configurations, then you can always use the `include` directive in any context, as per http://nginx.org/r/include.

Comment: auth_request sets an uri to be used to do the actual auth. Even if it's defined in http context, the respective location would still need to be defined for each server - not much benefit from it

Comment: @ffeast, are you saying the request URI has to be relative?  I haven't tried it out yet, I guess it might make sense for nginx to have such a limitation, but then it makes little sense why the directive is allowed outside of the server context.  Can anyone confirm either way?

Comment: I tried to use it with http:// prefix and it was just resolved as a location against the server configuration I used. You might try it out yourself, I may have missed something